# Got error on invoking the IBM Softlayer "getCpuMetricImage" rest API

Tags: rest, cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I have an active IBM Softlayer account. I am getting the error as

---

**{"error":"One of types passed is not in the proper container.",
"code":"SoftLayer_Exception_Metric_Tracking_Object_InvalidDataType"}**

---

when trying to fetch the **cpu metric image** using the below rest API with valid Virtual_Guest_Id and Snapshot_Range":

```
"api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/<Virtual_Guest_Id>/getCpuMetricImage/<Snapshot_Range>"
```

But I am getting the **proper response** while fetching the **memory metric image** using the similar rest API listed below:

```
"api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/<Virtual_Guest_Id>/getMemoryMetricImage/<Snapshot_Range>"
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all your REST request is wrong it should something like this:

```
POST https://$USERNAME:$APIKEY@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/$VSIID/getCpuMetricImage

PAYLOAD:
{
    "parameters": ["day","9/2/2017"]
}
```

Second the method is not working currently I am going to report it, but I do not have idea when they are going to fix it.

Another thing to point out is that the Softlayer's control portal do not use that method to display the graph, so is likely that the image returned by the method and the graph in the portal are going to be different. If you want the same inforamtion I recomend you to use the same method see this forum for more information:

[SoftLayer API CPU usage mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41830522/softlayer-api-cpu-usage-mismatch)

The method in the forum above will return you the data of the graph and then you are going to need to represent that information in a graph using your own code.

Regards